# Slide out html menu for mobile / ipad etc

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad, mobile

I want a slide in/out menu for the ipad/mobile device platform for my responsive CSS website. I've hand written one which sort of works but doesn't allow sliding to close or clicking outside to close (have to use the close button).

All the examples I've seen use wordpress I'm writing pure html/jquery/css.

Does anyone have a good fix for this? I tried jquery mobile panel but it didn't work as I wanted, because it's not really a mobile site I guess.

My main HTML is

```
<div>
    <h2>Lorum ipsum 5 times for length</h2>

    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</p>

    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</p>

    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</p>

    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</p>

    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</p>
</div>
```

And my menu is:

```
<div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>An Item</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>An Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>An Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>An Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So the menu needs to slide in and out from the left. PLEH.

Comment: You just have to append a div to body,(with ideally absolute/fixed position) offset it so it takes the space  outside your menu when it's visible (and overlays the rest of the page) and bind a click function to it that will close it. That div can be transparent.

Comment: THanks, this may solve one of the issues listed, how do I size it to fit around my menu though?

Comment: Depends on the menu, but you can put it behind it, and play with z-index and get your menu above it. Alternatively you can attach a click handler to body (but excluding your menu) which will close it on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this sidr jQuery plugin http://www.berriart.com/sidr/.

its used for creating side menus and the easiest way to make your menu responsive.

The above website have a lot of documentation on how to implmement this plugin.

if you want to see an example of this working, go to [funkychristmasjumpers.com](http://www.funkychristmasjumpers.com) and check it out on a mobile.

good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this plugin does not let you click elsewhere on the screen to close.

Comment: you can open and close the menu's programatically, take a look at this part of the documentation http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#swipe-menu , and then you set up a touch listener for everywhere except the menu itself and call  $.sidr('close', 'menu-name');.

Comment: How do I "set up a touch listener for everywhere except the menu itself "?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').click(function(e){
  if (e.target.id !== 'menu' ) { 
    $('#menu').hide(); 
  }
});
```